# Prove that $\int_0^1 fg' = 0$ iff f is constant

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$, $g$ : $[0,1]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable, where $f$ is monotone. On $(0,1)$, $g(x) > g(1) = g(0)$. Prove that $\int_0^1 fg' = 0$ iff $f$ is constant.

If $f$ is constant, we can easily prove that $\int_0^1 fg' = 0$ by integration by parts. However, if $f$ is not a constant, I'm having a hard time to show that $\int_0^1 fg'$ can't be equal to zero. Could someone help me with this final part$?$

Answer (score 2):

With a constant $c=-g(0)$,

$$\int_0^1 fg'=[f(g+c)]_0^1-\int_0^1 f'(g+c)=-\int_0^1 f'(g+c)$$

It's the integration by parts with a constant added.

Now since $f$ is monotone, its derivative doesn't change sign, assume WLOG that $f'\geq0$. Since $g(x)+c>0$ for $x\in]0,1[$, you integrate a continuous function that is positive or zero. If $f'$ is not identically zero, the integral is thus positive.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ non-constant. Then
$$
\int_0^1 fg'\,dx = fg\bigg|_{x = 0}^1 - \int_0^1f'g\,\,dx\\
= (f(1)-f(0))g(0) - \int_0^1f'g\,\,dx\\
 = \int_0^1 f'\cdot g(0) dx - \int_0^1f'g\,dx\\
= \int_0^1 f'(g(0) - g)dx
$$
$g(0)-g$ is nonzero everywhere except at $0$ and $1$, and $f'$ must by assumption be non-zero somewhere. That gives a non-zero contribution to the integral. Also, the signs of $f'$ and $g(0)-g$ never changes (though in the case of $f'$, it could be zero somewhere), so that non-zero contribution cannot be cancelled at another party of the interval. Therefore the integral is non-zero.

Comment: I do not  understand  one  thing : How  do I  see  that  at  one  point  both  functions must  be  non-zero   Please  elaorate  a  little.

Comment: @user118494 First, $g(0)-g$ is non-zero _everywhere_ (except at $0$ and $1$). Second, we have assumed that $f$ is non-constant, which means that $f'$ is non-zero somewhere, which again, by continuity, means that it is non-zero at least on some interval. These two things come together nicely to the fact that they must be non-zero together at some point.

Comment: Right  after  hitting  "add  comment"  I saw  your  edit   of  the  answer and  I  completely  understood and  upvoted. I  think , I  typed  the  comment  and  you typed  the  edit  at  the  same  moment. :)